# about random discrete variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I need to solve this question but I can't.

Set $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $X$ as random discrete variable with this law
$\,\mathrm{f}_{X}\left(x\right) = k\, x\, p^x$ for $p \in \left(0,1\right)$ and $x$ in $\left\{1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$.

Evaluate the value of $k$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a clue how to start? (Hint: the probability mass function should sum to one). (also, I assume $p\in(0,1)$, not $[0,1)$?)

Comment: Yeah but I don't know what is $k(p + 2p^2 + 3p^3 +....)$.

Comment: p \in ]0,1[.Sorry.

Comment: @jonidioni   Hint: $$n p^{n-1} = {d \over dp} (p^{n})$$

Comment: I don't understood.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n = x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} = x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}(x^n) = x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ for $x\in(-1,1)$, where some steps may need justification.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} kxp^x=\frac{kp}{1-p}\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xp^{x-1}(1-p)=\frac{kp}{1-p}\frac{1}{1-p}=\frac{kp}{(1-p)^2}$$

where the second equality is due to the mean of geometric distribution with probability of success being $1-p$ is equal to be $\frac{1}{1-p}$.